# Remove specific lines from text file

Tags: regex, string, text

I have a huge log file containing a bunch of lines like:

```
...
Useful stuff
...
Finished 0 of 435
Finished 1 of 435
...
Finished 435 of 435
...
Other useful stuff
```

How to *elegantly* remove all the "Finished n of N" lines except "Finished N of N"?

This shall be done on Windows, with e.g. Python or GNU tools.

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @anubhava: no preference; it should just be possible to perform the task with a tool available for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/^Finished/ && $2!=$4 {next}1' logfile
...
Useful stuff
...
...
Finished 435 of 435
...
Other useful stuff
```

**Note:** For windows you might have to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Or maybe just `grep`?

Comment: @NigoroJr With `grep` it will be tricky to put a check if the two numbers are same isn't it?

Comment: @NigoroJr You can use `-P` option for `PCRE` regex with GNU `grep` . For example `grep -Pv '^Finished (\d+) of (?!\1$)\d+$' logfile`. It's just less readable than `awk`.

Comment: I am aware of the `-P` option but I remember reading in the `man` page that it's experimental. Anyways, your solution works just fine so it's all good :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with empty string substitution

```
^Finished (\d+) of (?!\1)\d+$
```

[Here is DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/6)

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QAh7c-196jHU1Cru)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^Finished (\d+) of (?!\1)\d+$', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"..."
subst = u""
 
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  Finished                 'Finished '
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \1
   of                      ' of '
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
  )                        end of look-ahead
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  $                        the end of the string
```

---

#### EDIT

One slight change in the regex pattern as per the comment below

```
^Finished (\d+) of (?!\1$)\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/8)